# jQuery does not load on page load on Internet Explorer 10; only loads on page refresh (F5)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, pageload

jQuery does not load on page load in Internet Explorer 10 and have to press (F5) / or refresh the page for it to load. On Chrome and Firefox it loads perfectly; it's just IE that's causing the issue. It seems to be like jQzoom is causing the issue because that the only script is failing to load on page load.

**jQzoom Script:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.jqzoom').jqzoom({
        zoomType: 'standard',
        lens:true,
        preloadImages: false,
        alwaysOn:false
    });
});
```

Function that I am using to link all the jQueries:

'jQzoom2' is the script mentioned above:

```
function et_load_lucid_scripts(){
if ( !is_admin() ){
    $template_dir = get_template_directory_uri();
    wp_enqueue_script('sc1', $template_dir . '/js/scroll/jquery-1.3.2.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('sc2', $template_dir . '/js/scroll/scroll-startstop.events.jquery.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jqzoom2', $template_dir . '/js/jq/jqzoom2.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('navigation', $template_dir . '/js/navigation/jquery1.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('navigation1', $template_dir . '/js/navigation/nav_touch.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jqzoom1', $template_dir . '/js/jq/jquery.jqzoom-core.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('tracklist', $template_dir . '/js/test/jquery.dataTables.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('new_tab', $template_dir . '/js/test/newtab.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('html5', $template_dir . '/js/html5.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('superfish', $template_dir . '/js/superfish.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('flexslider', $template_dir . '/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('fitvids', $template_dir . '/js/jquery.fitvids.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('custom_script', $template_dir . '/js/custom.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
}
if ( is_singular() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );

    $et_gf_enqueue_fonts = array();
    $et_gf_heading_font = sanitize_text_field( et_get_option( 'heading_font', 'none' ) );
    $et_gf_body_font = sanitize_text_field( et_get_option( 'body_font', 'none' ) );

    if ( 'none' != $et_gf_heading_font ) $et_gf_enqueue_fonts[] = $et_gf_heading_font;
    if ( 'none' != $et_gf_body_font ) $et_gf_enqueue_fonts[] = $et_gf_body_font;
    if ( ! empty( $et_gf_enqueue_fonts ) ) et_gf_enqueue_fonts( $et_gf_enqueue_fonts );
} 

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'et_load_lucid_scripts' );
```

Comment: Could you put together a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) that demonstrates the problem? That will make debugging much easier.

Comment: Hi Max, thanks for your reply.. i tried adding the scripts to the JS but they are not working in JS at all and probably due to the multiple scripts and linking i am using. Is there a way to force IE to reload/refresh particular pages only? This will resolve the issue. Thanks:)

Comment: any help plzzzzz? been tryin to get this to work for good hours plzzz

Comment: Is the page you're developing accessible? Maybe I could take a look there.

Comment: Hi Max, Thanks for helping me out.. yeah sure the page is http://www.nsmmusic.com/products/digital-jukeboxes/icon-lite/. The issue is that in IE the product images (jQzoom) does not work when the page loads and when you hit (F5) it only works then. Chrome / Firefox works perfectly it's just happening in IE. Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: You need to fix the code on that page before I can try to debug for IE. There's a script error on line 308 (Safari and FF): "this.node is undefined".

Answer (score 1):

Add <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10"> into the head of your page.

This may also fix other js issues with content sliders and images. Cheers